# How to post validate symfony form date field with current date?

Tags: forms, date, symfony-1.4

I am havibg problem with pre/form/post validation if symfony1.4 and its form.
I want to validate a field with current date. As it is current date, I dont have to supply it explicitely.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The proper method would be to pass the current date from action to forms as options and from form to validator again as as option.

```
$form->addOption("name","value");
$this->validatorSchema['field']=new myValidator(array('option1'=>'value);
```

The options above should be current date in our case.